# How can I use Google Cloud NL api for sentiment analysis?

Tags: python, twitter, textblob, google-cloud-nl

How can I use Google cloud NL api for sentiment analysis for tweets from Twitter with topic(Keyword) that I choose?

I can write python script that uses Twitter(Twitter api)that how people are feeling about a topic that I choose using python’s NL library “TextBlob”

```
 import tweepy from textblob import TextBlob

# Step 1 - Authenticate
consumer_key= 'CONSUMER_KEY_HERE'
consumer_secret= 'CONSUMER_SECRET_HERE'

access_token='ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE'
access_token_secret='ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_HERE'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

#Step 3 - Retrieve Tweets
public_tweets = api.search('Trump')



#CHALLENGE - Instead of printing out each tweet, save each Tweet to a CSV file
#and label each one as either 'positive' or 'negative', depending on the sentiment 
#You can decide the sentiment polarity threshold yourself


for tweet in public_tweets:
    print(tweet.text)

    #Step 4 Perform Sentiment Analysis on Tweets
    analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
    print(analysis.sentiment)
    print("")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `google-cloud` [python module](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python):

```
# Import the module and create a language client
from google.cloud import language
language_client = language.Client()

# Analyze the sentiment
document = language_client.document_from_html(tweet.text)
annotations = document.analyze_sentiment()
print(annotations.score, annotations.magnitude)
```

Also, you can use the `track` parameter in the [tweepy Streaming API](http://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.0/streaming_how_to.html#streaming-with-tweepy) to filter tweets on a particular topic in realtime.